# Similar eth_call for substrate

Tags: rpc, evm, custom-rpc

a function like we have in ethereum : `eth_call`  exists for substrate ?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you be a bit more explicit? Do you want to call an evm function from a substrate pallet?

Comment: @Squirrel no sorry, eth_call allow to call any evm function. I would like to know if there is something similar to call any substrate function within an rpc call ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually. There is a JSONRPC endpoint named `state_call`. It works in a similar way to `eth_call`.

You can see the definition [here](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/rpc/#callmethod-text-data-bytes-at-blockhash-bytes).